# Trigger "Start Without Debugging" in Shell

Tags: visual-studio, shell

Everyday, before starting to code, I have to open and start without debugging many Visual Studio solutions.

To automate this time-consuming process, i created a Shell script, which simply opens the Visual Studio solutions.

How can i also "trigger", for each solution, the "Start Without Debugging" command?

Here is the script i have:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser

$listOfProjects = (
    'F:\Work\Solution1.sln',
    'F:\Work\Solution2.sln',
    'F:\Work\Solution3.sln',
    'F:\Work\Solution4.sln'
)

foreach($item in $listOfProjects)
{
    # open the solution
    $proc = Start-Process $item
    $proc.WaitForExit()

    # trigger "Start Without Debugging" ?
}

Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

Comment: *Start Without Debugging* is just running an executable. Why not run the executables directlry instead of going round via VS?

Comment: Yes, but which is that executable?

Comment: Many ways to figure that out - manually, or by building the projects and grepping for the lines conatining `projectname -> exe`, or use an msbuild scrip in which you import the other projects and check what their `TargetPath` property is